# Using vim to develop instead of Emacs on Windows

Tags: vim, emacs

I have used Emacs for a long time, say, 6 or 7 years. And it seems that I got Emacs Pinky somehow. Now I am trying to switch to vim, and it's a very good editor, just like Emacs, except that I wonder how you guys develop with it.

Using Emacs with a buffer running shell, I code, compile, debug, profile or do anything. But vim is just an editor. I still don't know how to quick edit in command mode, where everything go back to stone age. Should I use other tools, like [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/screen.html), as the environment, and vim just the editor?

FYI, I mainly work on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried using evil-mode on Emacs?  It would certainly be a lot easier changing the keyboard shortcuts on Emacs than switching to and learning a new editor.  I never use my pinky to hit the control or meta keys and I type 100 words per minute, and have been doing so since the early-1980's -- hitting all kinds of keyboards shortcuts with the control and alt and shift keys.  I can leave the home row and come back again blindfolded in fractions of a second.

Comment: @lawlist Someone suggested me evil-mode as well, but it seems weird switching between Emacs and vim state while editing a single file. I will take a try, thank you.

Comment: @lawlist: Put your comment as an answer. OP: Consider accepting that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those Emacs users wishing to have a Vim experience in terms of keyboard shortcuts and certain functions specifically designed to duplicate Vim behavior, the original poster may wish to consider using `evil-mode`:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil

In addition, the user may wish to configure his/her own keyboard shortcuts that make more sense based upon any physical limitations (e.g., pain in certain digits, etc.).

Finally, there is no requirement that a user keep his/her hands on the home row and stretch for the control/alt/command keys with a pinky.  It is possible to type 100 words per minute or faster, hit keyboard shortcuts using two hands away from home row, and return to the home row blindfolded.